# Displaying number of years worked since joined date

Tags: mysql, sql

List all keepers that earn more than $37,000 a year at the zoo. Show the keepers name, the total salary for a year (assume 38hrs week) and the number of years they have worked at the zoo.

```
Select surname
     , given
     , RatePerHour*38*52 
  From Keeper
 Where ‘ratePerHour’ *38*52 > 37000
```

This is what i've got so far, not sure how I'm supposed to display number of years worked?

Theres a "joined" table that shows date joined at the company.

I thought about trying '2019-03-08' - 'Joined' but that displayed the incorrect answer.

Comment: please show your table and give also some example data.

Comment: Or try asking in the psychic forum.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess would be to utilize mySql's CURDATE() function to fetch the current date rather than hard coding today's date.

Then you can use DATEDIFF(%FutureDate%, %PastDate%) function to calculate the number of days worked and finally convert those number of days in a yearly representation.